# What is it that is statistically significant? What does the phrase "statistically significant" apply to?

Tags: statistical-significance, terminology

This is a terminological question (now heavily edited).

I have two yes/no questions – Question 1 and Question 2 – that differ by only one word. My hypothesis is that response is related to wording (in respect of that one word). I randomly assign the questions to 200 people. Here are the results:

|  | **Yes** | **No** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Question 1** | 70 | 30 |
| **Question 2** | 20 | 80 |

A chi-squared test of independence gives me a p-value of less than 0.01.

Which of the following sentences contains a correct use of "statistically significant"?

1. The distribution of responses is statistically significant.
2. The difference between the observed distribution of responses and the expected distribution of responses is statistically significant.
3. The difference between the distribution of responses for Question 1 and the distribution of responses for Question 2 is statistically significant.
4. The effect is statistically significant.
5. The p-value is statistically significant.

If none of these contains a correct use of "statistically significant", can you please provide a true sentence of the form "... is statistically significant" that applies to this example?

Comment: None of the above.  Do you have a context in mind that could clarify the possible meanings?

Comment: The table was supposed to supply the context, but I'm guessing from your response that it fails to do that. What else do you need?

Comment: More context is needed, like a quotation or a description of the setting in which these data appear and what decisions are being made with them.  "Significant" usually refers to the result of a formal statistical hypothesis test, but many non-statistical writers use the word loosely in various senses.

Comment: @Remster to clarify a little further: in particular, that (pretty common but frequently misleading) use of 'significant' refers to an outcome where some hypothesis test has led the author to reject the null hypothesis at their chosen significance level. That use of the term does not necessarily imply that it is in any way important, or even useful (as you might assume from the ordinary meaning of the word). . . .  Personally I'd rather people avoided using the term in this way $-$ most especially when laypeople talk about *data* as being 'significant' and don't even explicitly mention a test.

Comment: As whuber says, more context is needed to be confident about the author's actual intent here. It's not possible to be quite sure that 'statistical significance' (in the sense of some rejected null hypothesis, and if so, which precise one) is the intent.

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide more context without overhauling my original post. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: In case I'm not allowed to overhaul my original post, here's an example of the sort of thing that's confusing me: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/statistically_significant.asp. On this page alone, the phrase "statistically significant" is applied variously to "a p-value of 5% or lower", "the data", "the result of a data set", a "reduction in type 1 diabetes", and a "difference between the means of two variables".

Comment: Not only can you edit your post, *you are encouraged to do so.*  Please [take the tour of the site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) and focus especially on the section titled "Improve posts by editing or commenting."

Comment: Thanks. I've now edited my original post.